# EDID is not loading from /lib/firmware

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, devices, edid

I wanted to load customized edid so I have added it's name as "drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=edid/edid.bin" and I kept the edid under `/lib/firmware/edid/`.

But after booting the system, I cross checked from user space. It is not loading: `cat /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/edid_firmware`.

I've enabled the configurations `DRM_LOAD_EDID_FIRMWARE=y`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

check what the kernel says at boot time with `dmesg -H`.
In my case with a similar config:

```
[  +0.000001] Kernel command line: (removed irrelevant options) drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=edid/2560x1440.bin 
[  +0.000180] [drm] drm_kms_firmware.edid_firmware is deprecated, please use drm.edid_firmware intead.
```

later...

```
[  +0.003042] [drm:drm_load_edid_firmware] *ERROR* Size of EDID firmware "edid/2560x1440.bin" is invalid (expected 0, got 127
```

Not sure what the cause is, but you should see some errors about your EDID file too.

EDIT: changed `drm_kms_firmware.edid_firmware` to `drm.edid_firmware`, still have the invalid size error.